# Add Image To Navigation Drawer Toolbar and Set Custom Background

Tags: android

I need to add an image to the navigation drawer toolbar/actionbar.  A small round image that appears on the right of the menu icon and left of the activity title.
I also need to change the background of the toolbar/actionbar to my own custom image.

Is this possible and if yes how do I accomplish this in my android app?

Comment: Yes it is possible, look into the Toolbar and whether it makes sense for what you're trying to accomplish.

https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-App-ToolBar
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Toolbar.html

Comment: When I try adding a custom toolbar the navigation drawer's toolbar covers it at the top.

Comment: Thats a completely different issue tho. You wanted to find out whether the things you mentioned in the OP are possible, and I have showed you that they are. 

Try this tutorial. It uses a Toolbar with a NavigationView and if you go through the first 2 links I posted, you should be well on your way. These are the resources I used to help me less than 6 months ago. https://guides.codepath.com/android/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: I have been able to build my own custom toolbar but my question is unique to navigation drawer which I specified in my question.  I will check out your links and see if it helps.

Comment: "I need to add an image to the navigation drawer toolbar/actionbar" as far as I know the navigation drawer doesn't have a toolbar/actionbar. Are you talking about the NavigationView header?

Comment: No not the header, the toolbar itself.  When I create a navigation drawer activity in my android studio a toolbar is displayed when I run the app plus it has the menu icon to toggle the navigation drawer view.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129377/discussion-between-mikeoscarecho-and-user3718908).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone confused, OP is using Android Studio's NavigationView Activity and not an Empty Activity.

Image to the right of the Hamburger menu icon and to the left of the Title is achieved like this:

```
Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); // hide built-in Title

    // Setting background using a drawable
    Drawable toolbarBackground = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_menu_gallery);
    getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(toolbarBackground);
}
```

Now that we've hidden the title, we're going to add our own title TextView and icon ImageView to the toolbar, this would be your `app_bar_main.xml` layout (res/layout).

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
    app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/my_custom_icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_menu_share"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="My Custom Title"
            android:id="@+id/my_custom_title"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menu_icon"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Now, you can reference my_custom_title and my_custom_icon and add whatever title and icon you want (you may have to tinker with the layout, I'm just pointing you in the right direction).

```
TextView myCustomTitleTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.my_custom_title);
myCustomTitleTV.setText("My Custom Title");
```